# Что вызывает ошибку SIGPIPE?

Tags: linux, c, сокет

Создаю неблокирующий сокет, выполняю `connect`. С помощью `select` проверяю что можно отправлять данные в сокет. При этом с другой стороной соединения нет.

Пытаюсь отправить данные в сокет и ловлю ошибку **SIGPIPE**. В связи с этим есть пара вопросов:

- Как мог `select` вернуть `1` при проверке на запись если обратной стороны нет?
- Если это нормальное поведение, то как узнать что подключение произведено?
- Если не было произведено подключение, то как могла возникнуть ошибка **SIGPIPE**,  означающая, если я не ошибаюсь, обрыв соединения?

**UPD**:

Вот минимальный пример

```
int main()
{
    int sockfd = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if ( sockfd == -1 )
        printf("Error\n");

    //Говорим что сокет неблокирующий
    int arg = ::fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL);
    long flags = arg & ~O_NONBLOCK;
    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    ::fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags);

    //Создаем запрос на подключение
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(10502);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.14.0.121");
    int rc = ::connect(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    int err = errno;//errno == EINPROGRESS 

    fd_set fdRead;
    fd_set fdWrite;
    fd_set fdExcept;
    FD_ZERO(&fdRead);
    FD_ZERO(&fdWrite);
    FD_ZERO(&fdExcept);

    FD_SET(sockfd, &fdWrite);

    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec  = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 500;

    // здесь select возвращает 1
    rc = ::select(int(sockfd) + 1, &fdRead, &fdWrite, &fdExcept, &tv);

    //здесь пытаюсь проверить сокет на отсутствие ошибок, но  rc == -1.
    // errno == EFAULT 
    int value;
    int length = sizeof(value);
    rc = ::getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, reinterpret_cast<char*>(value), (socklen_t*)&length);
    err = errno;


    //Здесь SIGPIPE
    char buffer[1];
    buffer[0] = '0';
    rc = ::send(sockfd, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer), sizeof(buffer), 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, ваш код.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov обновил вопрос

Comment: Что это за вызовы `fcntl` такие? Где дескриптор файла?

Comment: Ну так если getsockopt сообщил об ошибке, то в чем вопрос? Соединение не было установлено, так бывает...

Comment: Странно, что errno после select EFAULT (Bad Adress)... Обычно либо истекает таймаут и select возвращает 0, либо по готовности неблокируемого сокета на запись getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR ... возвращает в value 0.  В общем, тут надо убедиться, что select (проще программировать с poll) вернул доступность сокета для записи и в value 0 (это означает, что connect завершен), а не EINPROGRESS, которое он вернет сразу после connect (если не ждать)

Comment: По сигналу SIGPIPE пробивать работу с наследуемым сокет дескриптором. Или выключить SIGPIPE с помощью команды signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGNORE) как вариант, зависит от логике обработки соединения в приложении.

Comment: .И событие фдсет-врайт на сокете не очень разумно обрабатывать, оно всегда true, кроме случая если сокет был закрыт или была команда shutdown. В select вместо fdWrite впишите NULL. Также, проверять переменную rc, и если SO_ERROR вернул не ноль, не раздумывая выходить из функции и закрывать сокет.

Comment: И socket понимает флаг O_NONBLOCK, вместо беготни с fcntl :)

Comment: Да, забыл уточнить, в SO_ERROR проверять не только возврат функции, что естественно, а именно значение value :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверять через `select` на запись лишено смысла, сокет всегда готов для записи за исключением закрытого сокета или состояния после команды `shutdown` с параметрами `SHUT_WR` или `SHUT_RDWR`. С не блокируемыми сокетами еще веселее.

Разумно проверять состояние сокета через `getsockopt(.. SO_ERROR ..)`, пример такой функции:

```
int socket_iserror(int sock)
{
   int se = 0;
   socklen_t sl = sizeof(int);
   errno = 0;

   #if defined(SO_ERROR)
   if (getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &se, &sl) < 0)
   {
      switch(errno)
      {
         case EINTR:
         #if defined(EAGAIN)
         case EAGAIN:
         #elif defined(EWOULDBLOCK)
         case EWOULDBLOCK:
         #endif
         {
            return 0;
         }
         default:
         {
            return -1;
         }
      }
   }
   switch(se)
   {
      case 0:
      case EINTR:
      {
         return 0;
      }
      case ETIMEDOUT:
      {
         errno = ETIMEDOUT;
         return -1;
      }
      case ECONNRESET:
      {
         errno = ECONNRESET;
         return -1;
      }
      default:
      {
         errno = se;
         return se;
      }
  }
  #else
  return 0;
  #endif
}
```

В дополнении к этому, чтобы предотвращать фатальное действие сигнала SIGPIPE при приеме/передаче, необходимо добавить в начало каждого треда, если апликация много поточная, или в функцию `main()` следующее:

```
sigaction(SIGPIPE, &(struct sigaction){SIG_IGN}, NULL);
```

при этом, в случаях `send()/write()` будет возвращаться ошибка `-1` и errno устанавливаться в `EPIPE`.

Пример как с этим работать:

```
int ret;
if ((ret = socket_iserror(sockfd)) != 0)
{
    //return, break если цикл (с закрытием сокета)
{
if ((ret = send(sockfd, ..., ..., 0)) < 0)
{
    #if defined(EAGAIN)
    if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EINTR))
    #elif defined(EWOULDBLOCK)
    if ((errno == EWOULDBLOCK) || (errno == EINTR))
    #endif
    {
        // повторить код: continue, если это тело в цикле;
        // это как раз не блокируемый сокет
    }
    if (errno == EPIPE)
    {
        // закрыть сокет и более не обращаться к нему;
    }
    // return, break если цикл (с закрытием сокета)
}
```

В двух словах вроде все, для полноты можно добавить:

инициализация не блокируемого сокета:

```
 #if (defined(LINUX_VERSION_CODE) && \
    (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,27)) && \
     defined(SOCK_NONBLOCK))

   if ((socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) < 0) { ... }

 #else
   // используйте fcntl
 #endif
```

обработка ошибок метода `connect` на не блокируемом сокете:

```
 if ((connect(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) && (errno != EINPROGRESS)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

> Как мог select вернуть 1 при проверке

Потому, что в вызове *select()* "проверяется доступность операции в/в без блокировки". А если Ваш сокет НЕблокирующий, то естественно, что *select()* слетает с ожидания сразу же. Вы чего хотите?

- БЛОКИРОВАТЬ операцию в/в на ожидании готовности
- НЕ блокировать и самому разбираться с готовностью ?

Comment: В одном потоке проводится проверка того что подключение установлено(для этого я использую `select`), если подключение установлено  то в другом потоке вызывается `send`. Вот при вызове `send` я и ловлю эту ошибку. Возможно я как-то неправильно проверяю событие подключения.

Comment: Это неважно - что и как Вы проверяете. Важно только одно: с точки зрения *select()* любой НЕблокированный сокет готов ВСЕГДА. Как юный пионер... :-)

Comment: Тому, кто мой ответ "проминусил" рекомендую в командной строке набрать команду *man 2 select* и внимательно прочитать, что там написано.

Comment: Ну так в том-то и вопрос, если я не могу с помощью `select` проверить событие подключение, то как тогда это сделать?

Comment: **как тогда это сделать?** - я не знаю всех тонкостей Вашей задачи, но за 20 лет работы с сокетами я ни разу не встречался с необходимостью использовать НЕблокирующие сокеты. Может быть Вам стоит доверить решение этой проблемы *select*?

Comment: Всегда select предназначался для работы с неблокирующими сокетами - и тут вдруг он не может с ними работать...

Comment: Взять pool/epool - обертки или разные сторонние библиотеки, например libuv, libevent итд. И не пытаться выстроить обвязку на асинхронный сокет, там под 100кб коду получается, если делать грамотно. Обязательно использовать сигналы, и постоянно перед/после операции проверять сокет на ошибки..